# NodeMCU crashes when attempting to call net.socket:connect()

Tags: sockets, lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I am attempting to send a broadcast packet to a certain port, but it seems that the code gives some weird errors for which I can't find a fix.
I've tried using net.socket:connect() and then calling the "send()" method, which didn't work, then I said that I should use the net.socket:on('connection') and *send* there, since I suppose net.socket:connect() isn't synchronous. But that gave a weird error too...

For this code:

```
function sendBroadcastPacket()
    bip = wifi.sta.getbroadcast()
    srv = net.createConnection(net.UDP,0)
    print('Trying to connect on: ', bip)
    srv:connect('9001', bip)
    srv:send("Broadcast packet from: "..NODE_ID, function(sent)
            print("Broadcasted packet! "..sent)
        end)
end
```

I receive the following error:

> PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (init.lua:24: attempt to
>   call method 'connect' (a nil value))

Line 24 is the *srv:connect* line.

After that I tried listening for the connection event first, to see if it worked that way:

```
function sendBroadcastPacket()
    bip = wifi.sta.getbroadcast()
    srv = net.createConnection(net.UDP,0)
    print('Trying to connect on: ', bip)
    srv:on('connection', function(sck, c)
        sck:send("Broadcast packet from: "..NODE_ID, function(sent)
            print("Broadcasted packet! "..sent)
        end)
    end)

    srv:connect('9001', bip)
end
```

I receive the following error:

> PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (init.lua:24: invalid
>   callback name)

Line 24 is the *srv:on('connection')* line.

What seems to be happening here? There aren't many google results, since a lot of other people use the Arduino-IDE version(btw, is that still nodemcu or do you need a different firmware for the ESP8266?).
I am getting a broadcast IP, and it connects to the AP. I didn't post here the wifi connection part because it works, I've used it to test mqtt and http connections which worked.

The build I'm using,  Lua 5.1.4 on SDK 2.1.0(116b762), has the *net* module included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempts all failed because you don't seem to consider that UDP is a connection-less protocol. Hence, there's no `connect()` or `on('connection'...` for UDP.

The first attempt failed because `send()` needs to be called on a socket and not on the connection. The second failed because the `connection` callback name is only available for TCP, not for UDP.

Try something like this:

```
function sendBroadcastPacket()
  local port = 9001
  local bip = wifi.sta.getbroadcast()
  print(string.format("Broadcasting to %s:%d", bip, port))
  net.createUDPSocket():send(port, bip, "foo bar")
end
```

Documentation: https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/net/#netudpsocket-module

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot man :), I was really starting to lose hope thinking it was a platform bug.

Comment: I knew UDP is connectionless, but didn't really question the nodemcu method since I got inspired by some google results, and also, seems like somebody, perhaps you :), just edited the documentation wiki with that attention box where it says _This will change in upcoming releases so that net.createConnection will always create an unencrypted TCP connection_
I used Wayback machine to confirm that I'm not dreaming :)). I missed the createUDPSocket part in the documentation thoug.
Thanks again!

Comment: Don't trust the sources big G might lead you to. Our API documentation (the one matching your firmware branch) is the only source of truth.